# A consequence of the limit of the square of the norm being zero for a sequence of elements of Hilbert spaces

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

Let $\{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a family of elements of the Hilbert spaces $H_n$.

Suppose that $\underset{n\rightarrow+\infty}{\lim}\parallel x_n\parallel_n^2=0$. It seems reasonable to me that we can therefore say that there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that 
$$
      \underset{n=N+1}{\overset{\infty}{\sum}}\parallel x_n \parallel_n^2<\epsilon^2
$$
for any $\epsilon>0$.

However, I am not sure of this, and I am failing to see how one can prove it, if it is correct.

Comment: Is the norm important for this question?  Or is this question the same as asking: If a nonnegative sequence of real numbers $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ has $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} a_n=0$, can we conclude $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n < \infty$?  [and, can you answer the simplified question I just posed?]

Comment: @Michael Answer to your simplified question: no, we cannot. Just take the sequence $1/n$. And yes, my question seems to be equivalent to your simplified one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $H_n = \mathbb R^n$, and give each $H_n$ the Euclidean norm. Consider $x_n = (1/n,1/n,\ldots,1/n)$. Then $\|x_n\|_{H_n}^2 = \frac1{n}$ for each $n$. So $\sum \|x_n\|^2$ is the harmonic series - it diverges.